# Executing native code in the browser

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, google-chrome-extension, npapi

I have a library written in C++ which works with raw HID input (mice, touchpads, etc.).

I would like to create an extension, plugin, Java applet or whatever (preferably for Google Chrome), which would allow me to use the library in the browser on the client-side. But I do not have previous experience and I am not sure how to do it and what to learn to achieve that.

I read that NPAPI support will be removed from Google Chrome.

Please tell me how can I do that?

What I have:

1. The library itself (for Mac OS, Windows and Linux)
2. The bindings Java, Python and Node.js

I was thinking of making use of the Node bindings in order to use the library in the browser.

Comment: Also, not "will be removed", but "has been removed".  Google Chrome 45 was released yesterday which has no NPAPI support

Answer (score 2):

Native Client might work, but likely not unless what you need is accessible via native client APIs; you don't have full access to the system with Native Client.

Native Messaging may be a better fit, since you could actually write it using python or node.js if you want to (though it will require python or node to be installed to use it).

https://developer.chrome.com/native-messaging

FireBreath2 (still in sparsely documented beta) supports native messaging.

Comment: Native Client seems to be no longer available in Chrome, but there are still [several emulators in JavaScript](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25162/x86-emulator-in-javascript-to-run-linux-windows-or-dos) that can run native x86 binaries.

Comment: It's true that native client has been removed since I wrote this answer, but at this point a better option than using some kind of emulator is to use emscripten to build your library as a WASM binary and use that -- it's supported by most modern browsers and performs nearly as well as pnacl did.